# Factory Girl - writing tests for non-activerecord classes, for their static methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a two questions:

#### 2: secondary question

Is it correct to use factories for non-activerecord classes? I just do it:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :stations, :class => Transactions::Stations do |f|
  end
end
```

-- where Stations is not an `ActiveRecord` type. It is works, with some limitations in spec definition:

```
describe "Transactions:Stations" do
  it 'has valid factory' do
    FactoryGirl.create(:stations) # undefined method `save!` error
    expect { FactoryGirl.build(:stations) }.to_not raise_error # OK
  end    
end
```

### 1: primary question

How to perform a static (class) methods tests within Factory Girl?
I do it in not-Factory way right now:

```
expect(Transactions::Stations.find("MIX")).to_not be_blank
```

Comment: Why is primary question number 2 and secondary question number 1?

Comment: is it ok after I updated it?